# MAUI - alter programmatically child objects

Tags: dynamic, components, maui, child-objects

I wanna alter via code behind some properties (taking data from a DB)...

As a test, I've tryid this solution

```
  View v = this.Content;
  List<IVisualTreeElement> elements = (List<IVisualTreeElement>)v.GetVisualTreeDescendants();
  foreach (IVisualTreeElement button in elements)
  {
      if (button is Button)
      {
          Button myButton= (Button)button;
          myButton.IsVisible = false;
          myButton.TextColor = Colors.DeepPink;
      }
  }
```

but won't work (don't know why...)

What caon I do?

Google & doc searched,

Comment: Do this with data binding, not by directly manipulating UI elements

Comment: usually true but it's easier when receiving the config from a WS to manipulate directly ui using generic methods instead of modifing 1-by-1 a databinding.. with a pair of for loops is all done...

Comment: You can accept your own answer. This may help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes... after 4 times I've compiled with brakpoints etc...works. Don't ask me why.